# WSS with red5 not loading

Tags: java, tomcat, red5, wss

I have minimal experience with java and tomcat.
I am trying to get wss going so I can get an application to connect to my current running service.

I am trying to get avchat working in SSL for the mobile plugin. The support they have is non-existent an have seen some things on google but need some help with my errors.

I have added this code to jee-container.xml

```
<bean id="webSocketTransport" class="org.red5.net.websocket.WebSocketTransport">
    <property name="addresses">
        <list>
            <value>${ws.host}:${ws.port}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="webSocketTransportSecure" class="org.red5.net.websocket.WebSocketTransport">
    <property name="secureConfig">
        <bean id="webSocketSecureConfig" class="org.red5.net.websocket.SecureWebSocketConfiguration">
            <property name="keystoreType" value="JKS"/>
            <property name="keystoreFile" value="${rtmps.keystorefile}"/>
            <property name="keystorePassword" value="${rtmps.keystorepass}"/>
            <property name="truststoreFile" value="${rtmps.truststorefile}"/>
            <property name="truststorePassword" value="${rtmps.truststorepass}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="addresses">
        <list>
            <value>${wss.host}:${wss.port}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I start red5 i get this error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSocketSecureConfig' defined in class path resource [jee-container.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'keystoreType' of bean class [org.red5.net.websocket.SecureWebSocketConfiguration]: Bean property 'keystoreType' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'keystoreType' of bean class [org.red5.net.websocket.SecureWebSocketConfiguration]: Bean property 'keystoreType' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1525)
    ... 23 more
Bootstrap exit
```

Debug shows

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSocketTransportSecure' defined in cl                                                                                                   ass path resource [jee-container.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'webSocketSecureConfig' of type [org.red5.net.websocket.SecureWebSocketCon                                                                                                   figuration] while setting bean property 'secureConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error                                                                                                    creating bean with name 'webSocketSecureConfig' defined in class path resource [jee-container.xml]: Error setting property values; nested                                                                                                    exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'keystoreType' of bean class [org.red5.net.websocke                                                                                                   t.SecureWebSocketConfiguration]: Bean property 'keystoreType' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of                                                                                                    the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Comment: "Bean property 'keystoreType' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?"

Comment: @Mast not sure what that means

Comment: Remove this node `<property name="keystoreType" value="JKS"/>`

Comment: @PaulGregoire that looks like it may have got wss working, well at least red5 is starting now, thanks :]